# Is it possible to have a CPU/GPU/Network meter gadget in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

It was very convenient having gadgets for these stats in Windows 7, along with the graph history they display.  Can I still have this on Windows 8 or something similar without using 3rd party software?

Comment: Gadgets are culled in Windows 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although W8 does not support Gadgets anymore, there is a [couple of methods that gets them back](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/08/26/no-windows-8-desktop-gadgets-try-these-two-tools-to-get-them-back/).

One option uses gadget files [from the Release Preview of W8](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/35505-Windows-Sidebar-Gadgets-for-Windows-8-RTM-ADDED-32bit-Version), so it would not be 3rd party.

[8Gadgetpack](http://8gadgetpack.bplaced.net/) is another option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Resource Manager can do this.

1. Open the task manager.
2. Go to performance tab.
3. Right click on left bar, below the graphs.
4. Select "Summary View"

Answer (score 0):

well I am using rain meter and it is well supported in windows 8.so you can install rain meter and install the gadgets